Gitrunner takes too long to run build pipeline (25 Minute)
I have installed the gitrunner using helm chart I have mentioned below configuration in
values.yml
for one pipeline it takes 25 minute.
I have tried different configurations but didn't work
I am expecting build pipeline should take less time for e.g 7 Minute or less

I've got tests that take several hours. A number in isolation is meaningless.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
